# Linkbutton onclick not working in a Visual Webpart

Tags: 2010, web-part, event-handlers

I am having issues with the `onClick` event on `LinkButtons` (possibly all controls). These are not working in a Visual web-part. I am writing for SharePoint 2010.

Simple example of what I am doing:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Label1.Text = "load";
   }

  protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      Label1.Text = "click";
  }
}
```

---

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Web-part loads fine with `Label1` text being set to "load", but clicking on the button has no effect.

An ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `AutoPostBack="true"` to LinkButton and it will work fine.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" onclick="LinkButton1_Click">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

**[Update]**


Sorry for the missleading answer. Checked out the LinkButton - no ***AutoPostBack*** property, but there is ***PostBackUrl*** property - assign it the url of page that contains your web part and it will work - *tested*. For other controls like Buttons, DropDownList it's AutoPostBack to use.

Comment: LinkButton does not have the AutoPostBack attribute?

Comment: Dan, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Is there anyway to automatically determine this so that there is no hard coding.

Comment: In your code behind you can use **Request.Url.AbsoluteUri**

Comment: If it helped you do not forget to mark as answer)

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't reproduce this problem. Are you sure the controls are inside a form? This can happen if you have a mishap when editing the master page. Another possibility is if you change the attributes on the page or in the control, e.g. AutoEventWireup.

Comment: A Visual Webpart is a user control so its kinda hard to put the controls out of the form as there are no form tags. AutoEventWireup is set to true.

Comment: There will be a form tag in the rendered page - it will probably originate from the master page for the site page in which the webpart is rendered. You can check the rendered HTML.

Answer (score -1):

Add it in the CreateChildControls() event in the webpart, like:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{      
    LinkButton linkbutton = new LinkButton();
    linkbutton.Click += ClickButton;
    this.Controls.Add(linkbutton);

}

protected void ClickButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // handle event
}
```

Comment: This is a 2010 Visual Webpart, doesn't this defy the point of using a visual webpart, doing it this way the control wont appear in the designer\source view.